# Convert mov format video file to mp4 video in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

A flutter application that I developed uploads videos to the server,  iOS devices upload videos in the mov format, which the Edge browser does not support to play. I attempted to use swift code to convert the mov file to mp4. I'm receiving an error after referring to a code snippet.. By the way, I'm a beginner with Swift

Error : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unsupported value for standard codec'

```
            let myArgs = args as? [String: Any]
            let movpath = myArgs?["movpath"] as? String
            let mp4Path = myArgs?["mp4path"] as? String
            let movurl = URL(fileURLWithPath: movpath!)
            let mp4url = URL(fileURLWithPath: mp4Path!)
            let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: movurl, options: nil)


    //Create Export session

        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)

    // exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: mp4Quality)

   exportSession!.outputURL = mp4url
            exportSession!.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
             exportSession!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
             var start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0,preferredTimescale:  0)
            var range = CMTimeRangeMake(start:start, duration: avAsset.duration)
             exportSession!.timeRange = range

              exportSession!.exportAsynchronously {
                result(exportSession!.outputURL)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the code below

```
func encodeVideo(at videoURL: URL, completionHandler: ((URL?, Error?) -> Void)?)  {
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: nil)
        
    let startDate = Date()
        
    //Create Export session
    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else {
        completionHandler?(nil, nil)
        return
    }
        
    //Creating temp path to save the converted video
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
    let filePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("rendered-Video.mp4")
        
    //Check if the file already exists then remove the previous file
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: filePath)
        } catch {
            completionHandler?(nil, error)
        }
    }
        
    exportSession.outputURL = filePath
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 0)
    let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, avAsset.duration)
    exportSession.timeRange = range
        
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
        switch exportSession.status {
        case .failed:
            print(exportSession.error ?? "NO ERROR")
            completionHandler?(nil, exportSession.error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("Export canceled")
            completionHandler?(nil, nil)
        case .completed:
            //Video conversion finished
            let endDate = Date()
                
            let time = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            print(time)
            print("Successful!")
            print(exportSession.outputURL ?? "NO OUTPUT URL")
            completionHandler?(exportSession.outputURL, nil)
                
            default: break
        }
            
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks,
Iam getting an error : 
swift:92:25: Cannot find 'completionHandler' in scope
could you please tell me code lines to be added in my code compared to your code, this seems similar to my code snippet.